# A background view remains visible when you try to hide SearchBar through the alpha

Tags: hide, uinavigationitem, uisearchcontroller

I'm having trouble hiding SearchBar on NavigationItem.(Xcode 9 | Swift 4)
ex: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6is5mukpk1yew8e/bgSearch.gif?dl=0
Using this code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll (_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {  
    let transp: Float = Float (1 - (mTableView.contentOffset.y / (mTableView.contentSize.height - mTableView.frame.size.height) * 60))  
    self.navigationController! .navigationBar.alpha = CGFloat (transp)  
    self.mSearchController.searchBar.alpha = CGFloat (transp)  
    titleMsgView.alpha = CGFloat (transp)  
}
```

Everything works fine, except for a background that I could not access to hide with the alpha.
I'm using:

```
viewDidLoad() {  
    mSearchController = UISearchController (searchResultsController: nil)  
    mSearchController.delegate = self as? UISearchControllerDelegate  
    mSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self        
    navigationItem.searchController = mSearchController  
}
```

As the SerchBar search field disappears correctly, you will understand that it is something with the NavigationItem to which it has been added. Could someone help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try with you code it's working fine.

for your reference you can check line of code.

**here is link of that** :- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ceIF3rgOaw3YhfkcNJ1N-wc4phdvhYND/view?usp=sharing

Hope it's helps.!!

Comment: Thanks Nishee, but I give up using AMScrollingNavbar. I'm now keeping NavigationController and SearchBar stingy, simply using the alpha to hide them. I added a view just below to serve as a header. In the tableView I put a blank Header the same size as this view so the text does not overlap. The problem seems to me to be a bug. I can not access the background of the view (seems to be something of NavigationItem) to be able to hide it, since SearchBar normally works with alpha.

Comment: Yes. https://www.dropbox.com/s/97muhzslfl48yrf/ListTextParagMsgViewController.swift?dl=0